# A Proof of Bruns' Theorem

Tags: reference-request, online-resources, classical-mechanics

I am looking for a proof of Bruns' Theorem.

> **Theorem:** The 10 classical integrals of the three-body problem are the only algebraically independent integrals of this 18-degree-of-freedom system.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Sorry, @Shahab, I don't remember why I asked this question or in what context I found the theorem.